# Configuring Spring security with spring boot on already created project, IntelliJ

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have previous experience in Spring MVC but I am new to Spring Boot. 
I am Using IntelliJ for the first time.

What I noticed is that when you create a Spring boot project with security dependencies added during the time of creation, Then the IDE creates the project already configured With Basic Authentication whereas if I add dependencies to pom.xml after creation, then the application won't get configured with basic authentication automatically.

Can anyone explain this behavior of IntelliJ and can anyone help me with steps for configuring the pre-created project with Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is using

> https://start.spring.io/

to initialise your project. After the project is initialised, the IDE doesn't modify your code in any way. That is the normal behaviour and it is not Spring Boot related.

**NOTE:** The dependency that you add in your `pom.xml` is just pulling down that dependency, but if you need to use it you do the code yourself. *(More information about Maven: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven)*